# A question requesting for Official API documentation URL, counts as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

Sometime ago a user posted a question asking for an official documentation site, saying that it's very difficult to find it via Google (I agree). Yesterday, it was put on hold because it's off-topic. I agree with this type of flag when you are asking for your favorite "documentation" sites, but in this case the asker is asking for official documentation, something that I don't consider bad, seeing the difficulty to find via regular ways (such as asking Google).

My point of view is that it's a valid question.

The question in Stack Overflow: [Where can I find official / canonical documentation for using JavaScript with "classic" ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461339/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-classic-asp-that-uses-javascript-as-the-langu/11543662#11543662)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's a difference - subtle, perhaps - between asking for a recommendation and asking for help finding canonical documentation: obviously the asker here *does* know how to use Google, *has* found documentation using it, and is simply unable to find anything official-looking.

<sup><sub>(I can sympathize with that; in a former life, I spent a lot of time working with JScript, and Microsoft has made it progressively harder to find reliable information on its use for *anything* over the years.)</sub></sup>

Unlike a "recommendation" question, this *shouldn't* attract an endless stream of lazy answers: ideally, there'd only be one *right* answer (ideally being "in a world where MS didn't hate its JavaScript-loving users"). But of course, [the problem Pekka points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203147/a-question-requesting-for-official-api-documentation-url-counts-as-off-topic/203148#203148) is real: the question *didn't* make it clear enough that official documentation was desired, and the question was continuing to attract drive-by link-spam.

IMHO, this is an excellent use-case for the [Protect](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) feature: it requires answerers to have garnered at least a token amount of reputation on the site before they're allowed to answer.

I've re-opened and protected the question. I've also changed the title to emphasize the desire for *official* documentation.

Comment: i'm more sattisfied with this solution, Thank you very much. i think that all JScript community deserves this information .

Answer (score 11):

This is what the bottom part of the question looks like to a 10k+ user:

[image]

These are downvoted and deleted link-only and spam answers.

I don't deny the answer is useful and it would be cool to have around somewhere (at least at the moment), but the question has the same problems as every other question asking for a off-site resource:

- they tend to attract garbage
- they tend to attract opinionated answers
- and the answers are bound to become outdated eventually.

The fact that it's asking for official documentation that is hard to find doesn't change that.

Comment: +2 for an obvious spam link? Eugh

Comment: Surely the better solution is to edit the question to highlight that it is looking for official documentation only.

Comment: @TRiG it still wouldn't really fit the Stack Overflow format as it is defined currently.